# Compare (greater than or less than) 1st row value with 2nd row value based on Paid date for the Key, and then check if 3rd row is greater than 2nd

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Current result

-- ***Scenario1***--For ID 1 and 2, I want to compare if Diff Between (DD,Begin date of ID 2    , End Date OF ID 1) < = 1, then the value should be true and be displayed other wise don't display the value

***Scenario2*** For ID 10 and 11 -- Begin Date for ID 10 and Begin Date of ID 11 is same, so I want to compare based on Paid date, As Paid Date of ID 11 is > Paid date of ID 10. I want the value to be displayed which is greater

```
Id  Employeekey ReceiptNo   BeginDate   endDate     PaidDate    main    Supplier    RollNo
1   101         5505        3/28/2016   3/29/2016   4/29/2016   1       2001    655
2   101         5506        3/30/2016   4/1/2016    4/30/2016   1       2001    666
3   101         5507        4/5/2016    4/6/2016    4/30/2016   1       2001    155
4   101         5508        4/7/2016    4/10/2016   5/1/2016    1       2001    155
5   101         5509        4/11/2016   4/14/2016   5/5/2016    1       2001    155
6   101         5510        5/1/2016    5/3/2016    6/24/2016   1       2001    255
7   101         5511        5/1/2016    5/3/2016    6/30/2016   1       2001    265
8   102         5512        3/28/2017   3/29/2016   4/29/2017   1       2001    655
9   102         5513        3/28/2017   3/29/2016   4/29/2017   1       2001    655
10  102         5514        3/28/2017   3/29/2016   4/29/2017   1       2001    655
11  102         5515        3/28/2016   3/29/2016   5/29/2016   1       2001    655
12  102         5515        3/28/2016   3/29/2016   5/29/2016   1       2001    659
```

Comment: Hint: Row_number() in a cte or lead() or lag() for sql 2012+. Also you need to show expected results and what you have tried. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Thank you for the information and your help. I have added scenarios to make it more clear and added some columns.

Comment: Your question is still a bit unclear, can you add expected results. What do you mean by 'value' in scenario1? Do you always compare ID n and ID n+1 or should it be grouped by employeekey or receiptno?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the dates for your second scenario. The dates aren't the same for BeginDate for ID 10 and ID 11. Also, the PaidDate is not >, it's < (look at the years in both cases). With that being said, i edited your test data. Here is how you would do this. You can alter it to fit your needs but this will get you going.

```
declare @table table (id int, 
                     Employeekey int, 
                     RecieptNo int, 
                     BeginDate datetime, 
                     endDate datetime, 
                     PaidDate datetime, 
                     main int, 
                     Supplier int, 
                     RollNo int)
 insert into @table 
 values
(1,101,5505,'3/28/2016','3/29/2016','4/29/2016',1,2001,655),
(2,101,5506,'3/30/2016','4/1/2016','4/30/2016',1,2001,666),
(3,101,5507,'4/5/2016','4/6/2016','4/30/2016',1,2001,155),
(4,101,5508,'4/7/2016','4/10/2016','5/1/2016',1,2001,155),
(5,101,5509,'4/11/2016','4/14/2016','5/5/2016',1,2001,155),
(6,101,5510,'5/1/2016','5/3/2016','6/24/2016',1,2001,255),
(7,101,5511,'5/1/2016','5/3/2016','6/30/2016',1,2001,265),
(8,102,5512,'3/28/2017','3/29/2016','4/29/2017',1,2001,655),
(9,102,5513,'3/28/2017','3/29/2016','4/29/2017',1,2001,655),
(10,102,5514,'3/28/2016','3/29/2016','4/29/2016',1,2001,655),   --changed this to 2016 for being date and paid date
(11,102,5515,'3/28/2016','3/29/2016','5/29/2017',1,2001,655),   --changed this to 2017 for paid date
(12,102,5515,'3/28/2016','3/29/2016','5/29/2016',1,2001,659)



select
    *
    --scenario 1
    ,case 
        when datediff(day,lead(BeginDate) over (partition by EmployeeKey order by Id),endDate) <=1 then 'True' 
    end
    --scenario 2... id 10 and 11 have different years in your test but i fixed this in my test
    ,case 
        when lead(BeginDate) over (partition by EmployeeKey order by Id) = BeginDate
             and  lead(PaidDate) over (partition by EmployeeKey order by Id) > PaidDate then 'True' 
    end
from @table
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it helps a lot, and gives better understanding.

Comment: glad it helped @Avi